# D3 - attr "r" as compared to total screen size

Tags: d3.js

This may be a bit of an off question but I am trying to make a comparison of the "r" attribute of the circle in to the total width of the provided screen size. I want to do this because i have a topojson d3 map and some points with a circumfrence in km and I think it would be awesome to plot their r size in the provided km compared to the actual size on the map.

So - side to side it would be about 40006 km (around the earth), so I am trying to set up a conversion to make it look (kind of) the real size.

So what I am trying to determine is if there is an r value that is exactly or very close to 100% of the width so it wuld be like

```
  x                                    data in km
 _________           convert          ___________
 100% width r                          40006 km
```

where x should be the r size im looking for.

So I have a map that fits in a div responsively and I am wondering if there would be some way of determining an r value that would be 100% of that screen width. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To solve that problem, create a scale:

```
var scale = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0, 40006])
    .range([0, screenWidth]);
```

And then use it to get a single value, like this:

```
scale(40006) // Outputs the screen width
```

Or use it when creating your points, more or less like this:

```
svg.selectAll(".point").data(pointsData)
    .enter().append("circle")
        .attr("class", "point")
        .attr("r", scale)
        .attr("cx", ...)
        .attr("cy", ...);
```

For more on scales, check out [D3's wiki](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Quantitative-Scales).

To get the screen width, [pick your poison](http://ryanve.com/lab/dimensions/).